# report viewer using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have written 2 stored procedures in sql server 2008. one procedure returns one field value from one table and another procedure returns many field values from some tables. I need all values to be displayed in report viwer .rdlc(asp.net,c#) . How to use both 2 stored procedures at a time.

Comment: can you tell why you voted down?

Comment: hi why you use these 2 sp. u can join the two tables and u can use one sp with all fields